# String Format on LINQ controller statement MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, string-formatting

im having problems using String format on my LINQ but only on my Controller, using it on my view work well, so how can i change my LINQ to not give me an error in the Controller.

This is my **LINQ**

```
foreach (var item in db.Pos.Where(r => r.Fecha.Day.ToString() == "2").Select(g => new { Pdv = g.Pdv, Total = g.Total })
                                                      .GroupBy(l => l.Pdv).Select(z => new { Pdv = z.Key, Total = String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}",Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0) }))
        {
            listadepuntos.Add(item.ToString());
        }

        var grupoPdv = new SelectList(listadepuntos.ToList());
        ViewBag.GroupS = grupoPdv;
```

what i want is that the data of ViewBag.GroupS gets ',' each 3 digits , like for hundreds, thousands and millions right now i get the date plain without format.
what can i do?

Comment: why are you doing ToString instead of just comparing Day to the integer 2?

Comment: i dont want to compare it to 2, i want to compare it to actual date but i dont know how  and if i dont add to string it give me an error saying you cant compare a date with ==

Comment: If you want to do a date comparison then use a `DateTime` object set to the date an time you want to compare to.  `var dt = new DateTime(2016,2,25);` and then `r.Fecha == dt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method after your group by to execute your `Select` method using Linq to Objects instead Linq to Entities:

```
.GroupBy(l => l.Pdv)
.AsEnumerable()// Add this
.Select(z => new { Pdv = z.Key, Total = String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}",Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0) })
```

The issue is because your Linq provider doesn't know how to convert your method calls to a proper expression tree, which later need to be translated to a SQL statement. There is a few `string` methods that are currently supported (you will find them in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738681(v=vs.110).aspx)), `String.Format` is not one of them. In case of `Decimal.Round` which is either supported, you could use `System.Math.Round` instead.